Import content from parent script into gradle init script
I have centralized init script for gradle which I want to use in all the projects. So, I have configured my init.gradle like this:
apply from: 'https://gitlab.com/parent-repo/parent-project/-/raw/master/init.gradle
However, gradle build fails with this error:
Could not find method initscript() for arguments [init_3s9xjb5qrmtp3y78w08be6jzx$_run_closure1@5868ea91] on build of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.

Is there any way to import one init script into another?
Alternatively, if this is not supported, can we specify remote url for init script in gradle -I command?
